# Data context Class Missing in Identity

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identity

So I have a ASP Core 3.1 project and have managed to scaffold out via EF all the rest of my existing tables from my SQL server.

These all work fine and do as i need them to.
However when i go to add Identity to the project using my existing ASP User tables i cannot find the Data context class in the Scaffold menu.

I have already tried re-loading Identity, changing the base, and changing the startup file to look at the current database connection

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Scaffold Identity use the dbcontext which is in your project. If do not have any DbContext, you just need click the `+` on the right side of the DbContext selection to dynamic create a DbContext.  BTW, did your existing database contains all the Identity default tables?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was inheriting the superclass [DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext#defining-a-dbcontext-derived-class) in my ApplicationDbContext. Since I was using Identity platform, changed it to IdentityDbContext. It fixed my issue.

Comment: this. just make sure it's not `IdentityDbContext<T>` but just `IdentityDbContext` (otherwise it does not show up in the list). you can do generic stuff after scaffolding.